# Angular 2 - Http-Testing - Error: "Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null"

Tags: javascript, http, testing, angular

Always get this error in console, when running Jasmine Tests with karma on the following code:

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null

Service:

```
//http.service.ts
import {Injectable, Inject, ReflectiveInjector}    from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, Response, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from "rxjs";

const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(HTTP_PROVIDERS);
const http = injector.get(Http);

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor() {}

  httpTest(){
    return http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .map(response =>{ return response.json()});
  }
}
```

Testfile:

```
//http.service.spec.ts
import {
  it,
  describe,
  expect,
  inject,
  addProviders,
  beforeEach
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Http,
  BaseRequestOptions,
  Response,
  ResponseOptions
} from '@angular/http';


import { HttpService } from './http.service';

describe('Http-Test', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
      HttpService,
      BaseRequestOptions,
      MockBackend,
      {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
          return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
        },
        deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
      }
    ])
  });

  beforeEach(inject([MockBackend], (backend: MockBackend) => {
    const baseResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: 'userListAsJSON' }));
    backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => c.mockRespond(baseResponse));
  }));

  it('should return response when subscribed to httpTest',
    inject([HttpService], (testService: HttpService) => {
      testService.httpTest().subscribe((res: Response) => {
        expect(res.text()).toBe('userListAsJSON');
      });
    })
  );

})
```

Didn't finde anything why it can't *"read property 'getCookie' of null"*, or why it tries to read it at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a problem with XSRFStrategy provider.

Works if you create a fake XSRFStrategy in the test file and add as a provider.

```
class FakeXSRFStrategy implements XSRFStrategy {
  public configureRequest(req: Request) { /* */ }
}

const XRSF_MOCK = provide(XSRFStrategy, { useValue: new FakeXSRFStrategy() })
```