# Error: Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null when making http requests

Tags: angular, nativescript

I get this error *Cannot read property 'getCookie' of null*, whenever i try to make an http request. I was initially informed it could be due to using an old version of nativescript. I have updated all i can update and still have the same issue.
(versions: nativescript-angular: 1.0.0, angular/http: 2.0.0)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245831/angular-2-http-testing-error-cannot-read-property-getcookie-of-null) looks similar but it doesn't seem to have any ties with nativescript and i couldn't really understand the only given answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing **NativeScriptHttpModule** should do the job. Here is the code snippet.

```
import {NativeScriptHttpModule} from "nativescript-angular/http";

@NgModule({
.....
providers: [NativeScriptHttpModule]
.....
})
```

Comment: Okay, so the problem was that i was using angular's default httpmodule and this solved it. Thanks so much.

Comment: What is NativeScriptHttpModule and why do we need that?

Comment: ^ This. And where is it now? The import doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you have newest versions, quite possible that problem is same as here

> https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/305

**In short**: Try change all "HTTP_PROVIDERS" to "NS_HTTP_PROVIDERS"

Comment: i don't think that fix applies to the latest version. Angular's new http model does not seem to use HTTP_PROVIDERS at all.

Comment: Yea true for RC versions quite forgot about lastest :/